# Delphi TCoolBar - CoolBand alignment

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to align the CoolBands to the left side of the CoolBar? 
Means when the CoolBar (Form) is resized and the CoolBands move to the row below, the Band should be aligned to the left side of the Bar (instead to the right). 
Similar the menu behaviour, when the items doesn't fit into one row anymore.

Furthmore is it possible to save the adjustment of the Bands?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the MinWidth property of each band and set the CoolBar AutoSize property to True, it wraps automatically once a band is at its MinWidth.

***Edit***: The above is still correct, but should be expanded upon - new info from comments section. The Coolbar tries to always fill the width of the control, so your last band stretches to take up space. If you add MaxWidth constraints to the banded controls, they align to the right as the band wraps and stretches. The best solution here is to set your MinWidth to whatever you need but to let the CoolBar determine the max width.

Save the adjustment? Do you mean the exact placement of each coolband? If so, I don't think you can store it directly, no. But it should be trivial to reproduce the layout. Store the Break and Width properties of each Band and apply them in order. I think your best strategy would be to resize the form (or TCoolBar), apply Break for each band and then Width for each band (loop twice).

If that doesn't work, you could try calling the Windows message directly. This will allow you to set both properties at the same time.

```
uses
  CommCtrl;
...
var
  Info: TRebarBandInfo;
...
  ZeroMemory(@Info, SizeOf(Info));
  Info.cbSize := SizeOf(Info);
  Info.fMask := RBBIM_SIZE + RBBIM_STYLE;
  Info.cx := 400; // Your desired width
  Info.fStyle := RBBS_BREAK + OldStyle;
  SendMessage(Coolbar.Handle, RB_SETBANDINFO, 0, Integer(@Info));
```

That should work, but will require that you make *OldStyle* above equal to the existing style. That in turn will require that you either duplicate much of the code in TCoolBar.UpdateItem, or send the message RB_SETBANDINFO first. Painful, so try assigning Break and then Width.

In the Delphi Windows SDK helpfile, check Rebar Reference for info on all the messages if you need them. On mine, the help URL (for help viewer) is
ms-help://embarcadero.rs2009/ShellCC/platform/commctls/rebar/reflist.htm

Comment: AutoSize and MinWidth is already set and it wraps the Bands accordingly. But when the new row begins, the Band in the new row is then aligned to the right side. That looks a bit odd.

Comment: I don't see that. The band fills the entire row for me. And if I set a constraint on the control on the band, the band shifts left. Even when setting BiDi mode to right-to-left, I cannot get it to hang right.

Perhaps you can tell us more about settings on the bands, coolbar and form?

I'm running Window XP SP 3. Perhaps a Windows version thing?

Or perhaps there is an empty band that is taking

Comment: Also, are you happy with my answer on restoring the state?

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I thought there would be an easier way to save/load the state :(
Regarding the CoolBand alignment. When the band moves to the next row. The alignemnt is ok (left), but the last Band in the current row, moves then to the right side (right alignment). That makes me wondering.
BTW: Now I use the TToolBar control. That bar alignes the controls as expected when the form is resized.
Thanks

Comment: OK, I misunderstood the alignment issue then. The Coolbar AFAIK tries to always fill the width of the control, so your last band stretches to take up space. I tested with edit boxes on my bands and they always stretched to make up the space.

Adding MaxWidth constraints to the edit boxes I get your problem. My advice would be to set your MinWidth to whatever you need but to let the CoolBar determine the max width.